# How to get the last comment in Jira script listeners (Send custom email)

Tags: groovy, jira, jira-plugin

we have been using "Script Runner" plug-in to send custom emails. The below code works fine transition post function.

```
 <% if (lastComment)    
   out << lastComment
 %>
```

Whereas, the custom email in script listeners below line instead of the actual last comment

```
com.atlassian.jira.issue.comments.CommentImpl@4fexxxxx
```

Can you suggest a solution for this please.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [the documentation for that class](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/6.2.1/com/atlassian/jira/issue/comments/CommentImpl.html), you probably want to get the `lastComment.body`

Answer (score 0):

```
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
def lastcomment = ComponentAccessor.getCommentManager().getLastComment(issue)

if (lastcomment != null) {
return lastcomment.body
}

return null
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**.